# Delete child in one-to-many relation throws ObjectDeletedException

Tags: hibernate, one-to-many

I just don't understand why Hibernate throws exception mentioned in title. I probably don't understand state management idea behind Hibernate.

I have following situation:

**One-to-many relation between Organization and Employee**

Organization.hmb.xml

```
<set name="employees" inverse="true" cascade="save-update">  
    <key column="organization_id"/>  
    <one-to-many class="Employee"/>  
</set>
```

Employee.hbm.xml

```
<many-to-one name="organization" class="Organization"  column="organization_id" />
```

I use standard Spring/Hibernate app architecture with Services and DAOs, where DAOs extend HibernateDaoSupport class and use services of HibernateTemplate class for Session management.

When I try to delete Employee in this scenario...

```
Employee e=employeeService.read(1); 

//EDIT: Important! delete operation in EmployeeService is (@)transactional  
employeeService.delete(e); //this call just delegate execution to employeeDao.delete
```

**EDIT**: I did not mention at first that delete operation in Service layer is transactional which seems to be important info (keep reading)!

Hibernate throws...

```
 ObjectDeletedException: deleted object would be re-saved by cascade...
```

Delete operation in EmployeeService looks like...

```
  @Transactional public void delete(Employee emp){  
    Employee e=employeeDao.read(emp.getId());  
    if(e==null)  
        throw NoSuchOrganizationException();  

    /*...several while-s to delete relations where Employee is  
    not owner of relation... */

    employeeDao.delete(e);  
}
```

**Scenarios (they are not related):**
1. **When i remove cascade="save-update"** from relation mapping to Employee(s) in Organization.hbm.xml, **everything works fine**.
2. **When i remove @Transactional** annotation from delete method everything works fine.
3. **When i delete child(Employee) from parent(Organization) list of children**, and then execute delete, everything works fine.

**Question**:

**Why Hibernate  cares at all about cascade in parent class**?
**Where is the point in execution at which he considers cascade on Organization object**?
Why he just can't delete Employee(Child) with DELETE FROM... and that's it. Besides, Employee is the owner of relationship and operations executed on him should manage relation itself. **When he thought to call any operation on Organization object in mentioned scenario anyway**? I just don't get it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you may be missing is that Hibernate automatically maintains state for entities that have been loaded and exist in Session, meaning it will persist any changes made to them **irregardless** of whether you explicitly invoke "update()" method.

Considering your scenario, if you have loaded `Organization` and its `employees` set and are now trying to delete one of those employees, Hibernate is telling you (by throwing `ObjectDeletedException`) that it will re-save deleted employee when it will save `Organization` because you've declared that saving or updating should be cascaded from organization down to employees in its set.

The proper way to handle this would be to remove said employee from organization's `employees` set before deleting it thus preventing cascaded re-save.

**Edit (based on updated question):**

`Organization` **owns** collection of employees. Cascade always follows the association - you've declared it on `Organization` side, so changes (save / update) are propagated down to `Employee` level. As long as particular `Employee` instance is a member of `employees` collection of any `Organization` entity that lives in session, it will be saved (or re-saved, so Exception is thrown) when session is flushed / closed.

The fact that association is mapped from  `Employee` side (e.g. `organization_id` column resides in `Employee` table) is irrelevant here; it could have been mapped via join table with the same results. Hibernate maintains "state" via session and when you're trying to delete `Employee` without removing it from `Organization.employees` you're giving Hibernate conflicting instructions (since it's still alive - and has to be saved - in one place but is deleted in the other), hence the exception.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You were right, it works that way, but i did not load any Organization object previously. I still don't get it when Hibernate would consider any operation on Organization object in order to cascade anything. I gave lack of information at first, so i edited my question with more info-s that may be important.

Comment: Please sorry if I bother you with my questions. I did some more experimentation and i clarified some things. I just have one confusion: does Organization is saved automatically when session is closed/flushed regardless that there is no any explicit operation on Organization or on her list of Employees? In other words, when Organization instance is updated/saved?

Comment: @slomir - **all** entities that were loaded (by you directly or by Hibernate behind the scenes) in session **will** be persisted when session is flushed. That doesn't mean there's an actual UPDATE statement issued to the database for each entity, though - only actual changes are saved. If you haven't loaded your Organization directly, it was loaded by Hibernate via association on Employee (or some other entity, perhaps)

Comment: Thank You very much for answers. Thanks to you, now i got it :)

Comment: 1 issue...irregardless isn't a word.  You literally just said without-without-regard....:-|