# Hibernate - Dealing with "ObjectDeletedException"

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have checked other questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083826/unable-to-delete-entity-with-complex-parent-child-relationships), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971966/hibernate-delete-child-in-one-to-many-relation-throws-objectdeletedexception)) but haven't found what I need.

I'm modifying some existing code to add a feature.   I need to delete a series of related records in different tables.   The problem is that most of the entity classes weren't implemented with cascading Hibernate logic, but some of them were.   So by the time I get to the last collection, some of the records in this collection have already been deleted and some of them have not.   The relationship between two of the tables, Account and Address, looks like this:

```
@OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
@JoinColumn(name = "ADDRESS_ID", nullable = false)
private Address address;
```

This is causing a problem because I get an

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.ObjectDeletedException: deleted instance passed to merge
```

when I reach the subsequent delete:

```
    //This has embedded Accounts
     MasterRecord myMaster = masterService.findOne(someNumber);

    if (myMaster.getAccounts() != null) {
        // These have embedded Addresses
        accountService.delete(myMaster.getAccounts());
    }

    if (myMaster.getAddresses() != null) {
        //  Some of these are already deleted because of the previous statement
        //  ERROR OCCURS HERE
        addressService.delete(myMaster.getAddresses());
    }
```

I can't seem to get Hibernate to understand that I just want to delete everything in the Addresses collection, whether it's already deleted or not.    Is there a way around this, short of rewriting all the entity classes, which is really not an option?  Do I need to wrap each delete in a separate transaction and go ahead and let them cascade?   Is it safe to just tell the transaction to not roll back on that error, go ahead and commit?

**UPDATE**

Here is the service method and the SimpleJpaRepository method that it calls.   Javakid is correct - the SimpleJpaRepository method has its own `@Transaction` annotation.

```
//  Service Method
public void delete(Iterable<? extends T> entities) {
    repository.delete(entities);
}


//Repository method
@Transactional
public void delete(Iterable<? extends T> entities) {
    for (T entity : entities) {
        delete(entity);
    }
}
```

Removing the outside transaction and deleting each address from inside the account seems to work:

```
    if (myMaster.getAccounts() != null) {
         for (Account account : myMaster.getAccounts()) {
             addressService.delete(account.getAddress());
             myMaster.getAddresses().remove(account.getAddress());
             account.setAddress(null);
         }
        accountService.delete(myMaster.getAccounts());
    }
```

It seems like it could be simplified but at least it works.  Redoing the tables is not possible right now, but that might be the better solution.

Comment: is accountService.delete() and addressService.delete() are working in different transaction? Hibernate will simply ignore remove() call on an entity if it is already removed in same transaction.

Comment: We need to see your service methods implementation. I suspect you remove some entities and then you call update() to "update the removed state" which might end up failing with your posted exception. When you change an object state (add new children, change inner properties, remove) it's the flush() that does the sync, or a transaction commit() which call a flush anyway.

Comment: I updated the question - Javakid is correct, there was an inner transaction.   Updating the Hibernate objects to match what was going on inside the inner transaction seems to work for now. Thank you!  If you want to post as an answer I'll be happy to mark as correct.